# What is the definition of “blade scatter” in gas turbine compressor dynamic balancing?

Tags: turbine

Can someone help me define “blade scatter” gas turbine compressor dynamic balancing?

Comment: What help do you need? Is there something about an existing definition you don't understand?

Comment: I cant’t find the definition of “blade scatter

Comment: Do you have any context for this term?  Where/how is it being used?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete information. Actually I’m looking for phenomenon called “blade scatter” during dynamic balancing.
And it is due to what? Thanks

Comment: I’m guessing slightly here but I know that at least some turbines allow the blades to shift slightly around the axis of rotation, allowing the turbine to self-balance to some degree, particularly in a case where a blade parts company but also in normal operation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is an ellipsis somewhere in your source text, meaning the intended interpretation is **"blade weight scatter"**, which does make sense in the context of dynamic balancing.

The meaning should be self-explanatory: the distribution of weights among nominally-equal turbo-machinery blades, which is important to keep the inertia tensor of the assembly as diagonal as possible when using the usual axis.

Comment: Maybe "blade scatter" refers to [this](http://avherald.com/h?article=4cb6a09d&opt=2049)

Answer (score 1):

Bladed disks that allow for thermal expansion of blades at the root will allow the blades to "seat" themselves differently from run-to-run on the balancing machine. This causes the unbalance condition to vary slightly from balancing run to balancing run.

To reduce the effects of blade scatter, one typically takes multiple measurements and averages them together prior to making a correction.